# Python tkinter: creating and controlling many widgets

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

If I have many widgets, is there a widget index to conveniently control them? For example, suppose I need to create 10 by 10 labels, and I can run the following simple code:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
for i in range(10):
   for j in range(10):
      label = Label(root, text = f'{i}, {j}')
      label.grid(row = i, column = j, padx = 5, pady = 5)

root.mainloop()
```

The question is later how can I change the text of one specific label? Clearly, I don't want to manually define the labels one by one (i.e., label0_0, label0_1, ..., label9_9). So is there a way we can use something like widget index to control it? Something like

```
    from tkinter import *
    
    root = Tk()
    for i in range(10):
       for j in range(10):
          label[i][j] = Label(root, text = f'{i}, {j}')
          label[i][j].grid(row = i, column = j, padx = 5, pady = 5)
          # Clearly, there are mistakes here
    root.mainloop()
'''
```

Comment: Are you putting the `Label`s in a list? Do you know python lists work?

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```py
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
# Create an empty list for the labels
labels = []

for i in range(3):
    row = [] # Create an empty list for the row of labels
    for j in range(3):
        label = Label(root, text=f"{i}{j}")
        label.grid(row=i, column=j, padx=5, pady=5)
        row.append(label) # Put the new label at the end of the list
    labels.append(row) # Put the list of labels at the end of the list

print("All of the labels:", labels, end="\n\n")
print("labels[0]:", labels[0], end="\n\n")
print("labels[0][0]:", labels[0][0], end="\n\n")

# Change the text in labels[0][1]
labels[0][1].config(text="New text")

root.mainloop()
```

Look at what it prints out on the screen:

1. A list of lists that contain all of the `Label` objects
2. A list (the first row of the `Label`s)
3. The first `Label` on the first row.

Also just to show how to change a `Label`'s text I added `labels[0][1].config(text="New text")` which changes the text of the second label in the first row.

Please keep in mind that all python lists are 0 based. So to get the first item you use `list_name[0]`, to get the second item you use `list_name[1]`, ...